# What was Euler's misconception about functions and infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, functions

I just read this on Strichartz' *The way of Analysis*:

> [...] Euler - the leading mathematician of the eighteenth - developed all techniques needed for the study of Fourier series, but he never carried out the project. On the contrary, he argued in print *against* the possibility of representing functions as Fourier series, when this proposal was put forth by Daniel Bernoulli, and his argument was based on fundamental  misconceptions concerning the nature of functions and infinite series.

What were these misconceptions?

Comment: See e.g. http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/Functions.html

Comment: I'm not sure whether the question is about misconception that is related to his argument against Fourier series, or any misconception. But in general, he is known to have manipulated nonconvergence series, factoring out non-polynomial, taking logarithm of infinity, and so on. I'm sure you can find translated version of his work available publicly.

Comment: On pages 1 & 2 of Carlslaw's Fourier Series it says what Euler thought of Bernoulli's trigonometric series solution for the vibrating string: "Euler pointed out that if this statement of the solution were correct, an arbitrary function of a single variable must be developable in an infinite series of sines of multiples of the variable. This he held to be obviously impossible, since a series of sines is both periodic and odd, and he argued that if the arbitrary function had not both of these properties it could not be expanded in such a series".

Comment: Concerning the Bernoulli-Euler controversy see too this [review](http://books.google.com/books?id=VOcUBvbUXlEC&pg=PT192&lpg=PT192).